# How to work with Mac/GPT disks in Linux

Tags: linux, disk-image, gpt, partition

I use Ubuntu and Debian Linux.

I have an image of a (mac) disk that uses GPT.

How do I mount one of the partions on this?
I have installed gdisk and can list the partitions on the image.

I would actually like to extract an image of each of the partitions so I end up with an image for each partition.

How to do that?

Comment: It's easy to confuse "Mac" disks with [APM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Partition_Map), so avoid using that term inappropriately. GPT is GPT, on any machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @alharaka's suggestion will work, you might find it easier to use `kpartx`, as described in this blog post:

- http://nfolamp.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/mounting-raw-image-files-and-kpartx/

After attaching your disk image to a loop device, `kpartx` will create device nodes for each of the partitions. I believe `kpartx` supports GPT.

Comment: I solved the problem using kpartx and loopback devices.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://viaforensics.com/computer-forensics/howto-mount-hfs-image-partition-linux.html) should get you started.